# Microsoft Visual Studio unit tests - how to schedule runs?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mstest

We use visual studio for creating unit tests.  It suits our needs just fine but we can't find a way to schedule test runs.  Does anyone know how we could do this?  Perhaps there is an industry standard tool which would allow us to do such a thing?

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Continuous Integration. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already said @NickUdell, commonly test execution is a step in the continuous integration process, to this end in a Microsoft Windows environment, TFS is an obvious choice. TFS allows you to define a process for preparation and validation of the compilation through the execution of all types of test suites produced by Visual Studio.

**[Run tests in your build process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138.aspx)**

> You can use Team Foundation Build to run automated tests and analyze
>   the impact of code changes on your tests as part of your build
>   process.
>
> You can perform one or more test runs in your build that is based on
>   the Default Template.

The Default Template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml or GitTemplate.12.xaml) lets you quickly define a basic process that builds and tests your code. You have options to control the way Team Foundation Build (TFBuild) builds your code, runs your tests, and runs other processes such as scripts.

Although TFS do not provides built in solution for the deferred execution of tests outside the normal execution after the build, you can reach this goal through a simple batch file that contains the command MSTest.exe to run tests that you want (options reference of MSTest.exe) and the task scheduler for Windows;

This batch file accomplishes several tasks:

- Change to the folder of the project that you are testing.

  > **cd _solution folder**
- (Optional) Get the latest version of your source files and your test files.

  > The following command synchronizes only the current subtree:
  >
  > **tf get . /r**
  >
  > Or use the following command, which synchronizes your entire solution workspace:
  >
  > **tf get**
- Re-build the solution.

  > **msbuild .sln**
- Run the tests.

  > The following command runs tests only in one specific test metadata file. To specify a test list, use the /testlist option in combination with the /testmetadata option.
  >
  > **MSTest /testcontainer:\bin\debug\TestProject.dll**
  >
  > Or use the following command, which runs tests in an entire test metadata file:
  >
  > **MSTest /testmetadata:TestProject1.vsmdi**

**To schedule a batch file to run at regular intervals**

1. Click Start and then click Control Panel.
2. In Control Panel, double-click **Scheduled Tasks**.
3. Double-click Add Scheduled Task.
4. Locate the folder that contains the batch file that you wrote.
5. Under Perform this task, select the frequency with which you want the batch file to run.
6. Depending on the frequency you selected, the next page might require you to provide more detail about the times that you want the batch file to run, such as the start time and start date.
7. Type your user name and password. Done.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 introduced the new test runner, console info can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bhuvaneshwari/archive/2012/06/16/vstest-console-exe-commandline-test-runner.aspx